How to install mcedit on Linux Ubuntu?
I need to use mcedit to write my name to the file.
When I wrote mcedit text1.txt I got mcedit: command not found. What should I do?

To get mcedit, you need to install mc (Midnight Commander):
sudo apt install mc

To figure this out yourself in future, install apt-file:
sudo apt install apt-file
sudo apt update
apt-file search bin/mcedit


It wrote: Reading package lists... Done. Building dependency tree. Reading state information... Done. Package ms is not available, but is mentioned in another package's dependency list. This may mean that the package is missing, out of date, or available from sources not mentioned in sources.list
E. No installation candidate found for package "ms".

It’s mc, not ms.

I mixed it up when I was translating. "No installation candidate found for package mc"

OK, mc is in universe, have you enabled that?

you can download mc deb-package via packages.ubuntu.com choosing your current Ubuntu distro in drop-down menu.

I downloaded mc deb package, refreshed lists of packages from repositories "sudo apt update" and it worked!!! Thank you so much everyone!!!
